# With gulp, are watch tasks guaranteed to run before other tasks?

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch

I have a gulp watch task that uses `gulp-sass` to convert SASS to CSS. For development, separated CSS files are all I want.

For release, I have a `min` tasks that uses `gulp-cssmin` and `concat` to bundle and minify the CSS. However, the `min` task doesn't deal with the SASS files. It assumes they have already been converted to CSS.

Is this a valid assumption? What if an automated build gets the latest source (which does not have .scss files) and runs `min`? Is there a race condition here as to whether the watch task will run in time for `min` to pick up the SASS files?

Comment: They don't should run regarding the order in the pipe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `min` task is also watching the SASS files, your assumption is not necessarily valid. By default, all the tasks will run at the same time. You can however define dependencies in your task, so that a task does not start until another task is finished. This could solve your problem. The documentation about dependencies can be found [here](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md#gulptaskname-deps-fn).

There are also two other solutions:

- Watch the CSS files for the `min` task.
- Run the logic in your `min` task at the end of the task that compiles the SASS.

Answer (score 0):

Edward! Better use optional minification to prevent extra reading from the disk.

```
var env = require('minimist')(process.argv.slice(2));
var noop = require('readable-stream/passthrough').bind(null, { objectMode: true });
gulp.task('style', function () {
  return gulp.src('...')
    .pipe(process())
    .pipe(env.min ? uglify() : noop())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('...'))
});
```

Also I don't recommend these tools from gulp-util which will be deprecated

Answer (score 0):

Even if gulp guaranteed that it would wait for watch tasks to complete before starting dependent tasks, a race could still occur during the interval from when a source file is changed until the OS notifies gulp. So I decided not to use the SASS → CSS transform output. For as infrequently as I need to build the minimized versions, there's no payoff for saving those milliseconds.

Instead I used `stream-combiner2` to reuse the transform logic:

```
var combiner = require('stream-combiner2');

function scssTransform() {
    return combiner(
        sourcemaps.init(),
        sass(),
        sourcemaps.write());
}
```

I use the transform for my non-mimized "sandbox" for local development:

```
gulp.task('sandbox:css', function () {
    return gulp.src(paths.scss)
        .pipe(scssTransform())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(dirs.styles));
});
```

My task for serving the site locally depends on and watches the task:

```
gulp.task('serve.sandbox', ['sandbox:css' /* ... more ... */], function () {
    // ... Start the web server ...
    gulp.watch(paths.scss, ['sandbox:css']);
    // ... Watch more stuff ...
});
```

I also use the transform for my minimized deployment:

```
gulp.task('deploy:css', function () {
    return gulp.src(paths.scss)
        .pipe(scssTransform())
        .pipe(concat(files.cssMin))
        .pipe(cssmin())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(dirs.deploy));
});
```